# Windows Batch: Loop through to echo a set of variables

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that contains the code below which assigns a variable for each line in a text file.

So the text file might have:

```
RELEASE1
RELEASE2
RELEASE3
```

The batch file sets each line in the text file to var1, var2, var3 with the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (sites.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
)
```

I need a method to echo all the defined variables. The number of variables will always change. So it might go up to var8 or var10 etc...

I'm pretty certain a for loop would do the trick but not sure what the best approach or how to do it? I was thinking of using vidx as the number of iterations? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Easy

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (sites.txt) do (
SET /A count+= 1
set var!count!=%%A
)

Rem //:Notice That %count% still stores the last variable, use this in a "for /l" loop:

for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
Rem Below line is optional and displays variable number
<nul set /p="Variable %%a: "
Echo !var%%a!
)
```

That should work fine as long as none of the data contains parenthesis, in which case you'll have to escape them.

Type `for /?` for help on this. Ask If you want an explanation.

Comment: Parentheses need not be escaped when using delayed expansion. The only problem is if data contains `!` because delayed expansion will then corrupt value in first loop. The last two lines should be simplified to `echo Variable %%a: !var%%a!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
set var|findstr /R "var[0-9]*="
```

May be the shortest way....